# C++ std lib <mutex>, <conditional_variable> libs and shared memory

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

The C API to POSIX threads requires a special flag to be set if you want to share a mutex between processes in shared memory - see `sem_init()`. I don't really know what the diff is but I'm having trouble trying to use C++ std::condition_variable in shared memory - its seg faulting. I can't see anything mentioning this in the C++ docs, or the constructors. I was wondering how to / if you can use C++ thread mutex in shared memory. Here is my test code for reference. Note `squeue` is just a simple (POD) static sized circular queue, and irrelevant stuff is omitted:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>        /* For mode constants */
#include <fcntl.h>           /* For O_* constants */
#include "squeue.h"
#define SHM_FILENAME "/shimmy-foo"
#define SQUEUE_LENGTH 10

typedef struct {
        squeue<int,SQUEUE_LENGTH> queue;
        std::mutex mutex;
        std::condition_variable_any condvar;
} SHM;

int main() {
        int shm_fd = 0;
        SHM * shm_ptr = NULL;
        squeue<int,SQUEUE_LENGTH> * queue = NULL;
        std::mutex * mutex;
        std::condition_variable_any * condvar;

        // Init SHM. ftruncate() will zero area.
        if((shm_fd = shm_open(SHM_FILENAME, O_CREAT|O_RDWR|O_EXCL, S_IREAD|S_IWRITE)) == -1 ) {
            fprintf (stderr, "Could not open shm object. %s\n", strerror(errno));
            return errno;
        }
        else {
            fprintf (stderr, "Open shm OK. %d\n", shm_fd);
        }
        ftruncate(shm_fd, sizeof(SHM));

        // Connect the shmptr pointer to set to the shared memory area,
        // with desired permissions
        if((shm_ptr = (SHM*)mmap(0, sizeof(SHM), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0)) == MAP_FAILED) {
            fprintf (stderr, "Could not map shm. %s\n", strerror(errno));
            return errno;
        }
        else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Mapped shm OK. %p\n", shm_ptr);
        }

        // Create queue and mutex.
        queue = new(&shm_ptr->queue) squeue<int,SQUEUE_LENGTH>();
        mutex = new(&shm_ptr->mutex) std::mutex();
        condvar = new(&shm_ptr->condvar) std::condition_variable_any();

        srand(time(NULL));
        while(true) {
            cout << "Waiting on lock" << endl;
            mutex->lock();
            if(!queue->full()) {
                int value = rand()%100;
                queue->push(value);
                cout << "Pushed " << value << endl;
            } else {
                cout << "Que is full!" << endl;
            };
            condvar->notify_all(); //Seg fault.
            mutex->unlock();
            sleep(1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: OK thx for the advice on references.

Comment: @stefen I'd hardly have to qualify that the queue was irrelavent if the queue was not in the code. Its a very simple queue I'm sure it has nothing to do with the issue at hand.

Comment: @FrancisMBacon: That's what I'm talking about: If it has nothing to do with the error, remove it completely!

Comment: You cannot use non-POD C++ objects in shared memory.

Comment: @n.m. How do I know mutex etc is not POD? Also, why?

Comment: @n.m.: Boost.IPC anyone? Stateful allocators? Why did we do all this work giving tuples allocator-extensions...

Comment: You don't. That's the point. You also cannot use objects which allocate memory and store pointers beyond your control, which std::queue definitely does (IIRC you used to have std::queue in the code until it was deleted from the question). Why --- [see here](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&espv=2&q=c%2B%2B+objects+in+shared+memory+site%3Astackoverflow.com).

Comment: @n.m I did not use std::queue, and for that reason. So I guess there must be dyn allocation going on in std::condition_variable.

Comment: @KerrekSB Boost.IPC objects are specifically designed to be stored in shared memory so they carefully avoid stuff that makes them ineligible. (The POD requirement is probably an overkill, the real constraints should be weaker). All the work on stateful allocators and stuff is incredibly useful, but (1) you need to actually use them (2) you still need to avoid "advanced layout" objects if you want to use them in shared mem and (3) you need to hide raw internal pointers in shared-memory-aware wrappers. Code that was posted with the question IIRC didn't do any of this.

Comment: @n.m I will add back the code maybe you can pont exactly what you mean,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use a similar pattern, however, the standard mutex and condition variables are not designed to be shared between processes. The reason for that is that POSIX requires `PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED` attribute set on process shared mutexes and condition variables but the standard C++ primitives do not do that. On Windows it might be more complicated than that.

You can try using boost [process shared mutexes](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.mutexes) and [process shared condition variables](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.conditions) instead. Or create your own wrappers for POSIX interfaces.

---

It could also be that `squeue` corrupts memory beyond its buffer overwriting the mutex and the condition variable that lay above in memory in `struct SHM`. I would try commenting out the code that pushes into the queue and see if you still get that crash. I tried your code with queue code commented out and it works as expected.

---

You may also like to use `condition_variable` instead of `condition_variable_any`, because the latter one maintains its own mutex but that mutex is not needed if you notify that condition variable while having the associated mutex locked (as you do).

Comment: Great "The C++ classes don't set PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED" is pretty much the answer I was looking for. I replaced the C++ stuff with pthread_(cond|mutex)_t and its all working now. Thx.